# How To Remove Lines Containing Any Hash Type in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, editing, notepad

Full example file containing:

```
user:passowrd
user:199d8ddda49f7505c8d896c8d2e81011
user:c7c08cc091bbe531449f62dd76e2e7c86e1dfa01
user:8e38fe8363321acd83deb0fc65ea00f9
user:62fce586fcd5891becd5e6904e85e708
user:a366e6c3178e26cfdacdd74c47c9f3b6
user:f4c28c9c0b7d303faf59e4664535c8a2
user:feae98114804036567a4c1a3d454be36
```

Needed result:

```
user:passowrd
```

Answer (score 2):

If the word you're looking for only contains the characters abcdef and it's the same length as a hash it will be impossible to tell them apart with regex.

If you think that's unlikely you could search for

```
user:([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{40})$
```

That will match 32 or 40 digit hex numbers. Unfortunately it will also match 32 or 40 character words that only use the letters abcdef. So it will match `deafdeafdeafdeafdeafdeafdeafdeaf`.